# Angular 2 Component relative path on an application deployed on subpath

Tags: angular

I have a component like this

```
@Component({
    moduleId:__moduleName,
    selector:"awesome-component",
    templateUrl:"awesome.component.html",
    styleUrls:["awesome.component.css"]
})
export class AwesomeComponent {}
```

I bundle this using Systemjs builder and everything works OK when the app is deployed on the root path e.g. if the app is running from `http://localhost`.

It doesn't work when the app is running under a subpath e.g. `http://localhost/awesome-app`. This produces lot of 404 because the request for component's html and css files are made to the root e.g. `http://localhost/awesome-component.html` rather than to `http://localhost/awesome-app/awesome-component.html`. I have set base href to awesome-app e.g. `<base href="/awesome-app/">`

Is there any way to guide angular to send request to the subpath where the app is deployed rather than to the root?

Answer (score 0):

I guess not many developers have come across this issue even though I think this is a very common scenario. After few days of looking for options to configure angular/systemjs, I ended up generating the relative path of the template and style urls from the root of the site dynamically as follows

```
   function appendToBase(path: string): string {
        return getBase() + path;
    }

    function getBase(): string {
        let baseElement = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0];
        if (baseElement && baseElement.href) {
            var pathFragments = baseElement.href.split("/");
            if (pathFragments.length > 3) {
                pathFragments.splice(0, 3);
                return pathFragments.join("/");
            }
        }
        return "./";
    }
```

and changed the component metadata as follows

```
@Component({
    selector:"awesome-component",
    templateUrl:appendToBase("awesome.component.html"),
    styleUrls:[appendToBase("awesome.component.css")]
})
export class AwesomeComponent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar problem when I use both a custom base href path:

```html
<base href="/something-1/">
```

...and set a component's moduleId:

```js
@Component({
    moduleId: "something-2",
    selector:"my-component",
    ...
})
```

If the component's moduleId is not assigned, the component path resolves correctly with a specified base path.

I believe it's a bug.